# Subclassed UIView not displaying proper after animating frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, animated

I have subclassed `UIView` to contain basically a `UIPickerView` and a `UIToolbar`.

When the user selects a particular row in the picker I will then add a `UIImageView` over the picker. However this image is not visible when I have animated my `UIView` to slide up the screen. If I don't animate the `UIView` then it will display properly.

I'm displaying the `UIImageView` like this (in the `UIView`):

```
- (void)showMailSetupPopover {

    if (self.popoverMailSetupImageView == nil) {

        UIImageView *popoverMailSetupImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"popover-mail-setup-addreminder"]];
        popoverMailSetupImageView.alpha = 0.0;
        popoverMailSetupImageView.frame = CGRectMake(8, self.frame.origin.y + 65, popoverMailSetupImageView.bounds.size.width, popoverMailSetupImageView.bounds.size.height);
        self.popoverMailSetupImageView = popoverMailSetupImageView;
    }

    [self addSubview:self.popoverMailSetupImageView];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{

        self.popoverMailSetupImageView.alpha = 1.0;

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
}
```

This is how I add the`UIView` to `self.view`:

```
RMMessageTypePickerView *messageTypePickerView = [[RMMessageTypePickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height, 320, 260) reminderMessageType:RMReminderMessageTypeText delegate:self];

self.messageTypePickerView = messageTypePickerView;

[self.view addSubview:self.messageTypePickerView];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{

    self.messageTypePickerView.frame = messageTypePickerViewTargetFrame;
    self.addReminderTableView.frame = addReminderTableViewTargetFrame;

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    if (firstShow) {

        [self processSelectedMessageTypeRow:RMReminderMessageTypeText];
    }
}];
```

Comment: [self.view addSubview:self.messageTypePickerView]; -> put this into the animation completion block.

Comment: @pe60t0 i think you are completely wrong. if he would add the view in the completion block, then the animated movement of the view wouldn't be possible

Comment: @Peter Warbo, can you add the code where you call - (void)showMailSetupPopover

Answer (score 0):

Found out the issue,

Replaced

`popoverMailSetupImageView.frame = CGRectMake(8, self.frame.origin.y + 65, popoverMailSetupImageView.bounds.size.width, popoverMailSetupImageView.bounds.size.height);`

with

`popoverMailSetupImageView.frame = CGRectMake(8, 65, popoverMailSetupImageView.bounds.size.width, popoverMailSetupImageView.bounds.size.height);`

`self.frame.origin.y` is not needed.